# How to check if (key belongs to value/value belongs to key)

Tags: python, dictionary

I can't figure out how to check if the answer is right.

```
import random
elements = {"Co":"cobaltum",
            "C":"Carboneum"}
question = random.choice(list(elements.keys()))
print(question)
answer=input("What is the full name of this element? ")
```

Comment: `answer == elements[question]`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
if answer == elements[question]:
  print("you're right!")
```

...I think that's what you're asking. Basically you can access the value of a key in a dictionary like

```
myDict[key] # value
```